# Embed twitch stream with pause and delay option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to embed a twitch live stream on my website with a defined delay. (http://www.twitch.tv/)
Is there a way to buffer the video on client side using javascript or what tools could I use to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe src="http://www.twitch.tv/mmrr38/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/mmrr38?tt_medium=live_embed&tt_content=text_link" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline;">Watch live video from mmrr38 on www.twitch.tv</a>`